# Javascript issues with IE computerStyle.getPropertyValue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have the following code:

```
parseInt(computedStyle.getPropertyValue("width")
```

If I console.log it, it logs the expected result.

There seems to be an issue with the first time I call this code though. For example, if I did the following:

```
console.log(computedStyle.getPropertyValue("width");
console.log(computedStyle.getPropertyValue("width");
```

Only the second result would display the correct data.

This issue only occurs in IE. In all other browsers, the code works fine.

Is this a known IE issue?

(As a test, I've created dummy code at the top of my document - just a variable which = this data. Then all the following *computedStyle* works. Of course this isn't the fix I would like).

Comment: As a side note, `getComputedStyle` is supported only by IE >= 9 http://caniuse.com/#search=getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out it's returning a percentage, I just need to work out how to force it to return it in pixels.
Thanks guys